# Error com.android.dx.command.Main in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I have error when building project. Anybody have this error before. I updated to Android Studion2.3 and build normally, but now I don't know why having this error. Clean, Rebuild but still have this error.

My gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25'
```

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with
> >     arguments {--dex --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output
> >     D:\GIT
> >     TECHUB\pocca_android.git\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\5\slice_2
> >     D:\GIT
> >     TECHUB\pocca_android.git\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\folders\1\5\slice_2}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason, a file error log created in my app -- **insufficient memory**. I restart my computer and now I worked. But my computer 16Gb ram, Android Studio only use nearly 2Gb ram, but error still happen

**hs_err_pid4936.log**

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>    Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 604656 bytes for Chunk::new
>    Possible reasons:
>     The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
>      In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
>    Possible solutions:
>      Reduce memory load on the system
>      Increase physical memory or swap space
>      Check if swap backing store is full
>      Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
>     Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
>     Decrease number of Java threads
>      Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
>      Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
>    This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
>
> Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:390), pid=4936, tid=0x000000000000156c
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Comment: This was my case.  My computer has 24GB.  The project was build successfully after I closed a few programs to free memory.

Comment: Ah. You can check your partition containing Android Studio. I had that problem when I open Photoshop, Photoshop use a lot of disk space (My C partion is red, only a few MB :| ). I close Photoshop and it 's ok.

Answer (score 4):

add  multiDexEnabled true in default config file of build.gradle like this

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
       }
```

Comment: What if the project uses maven vs. gradle? I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole` regardless of how often I build, rebuild, reboot, reinstall, re-"everything else". :( @MoradiyaAkash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you didn't implement the multiple libraries in the same project. then project conflicted with both libraries.
If you face the problem please read the solution step one by one and apply the process to your error project.

- **Step 1**

Your google play services library is being exported from other dependencies of your project and at the compile time the dex compiler gets confused.
If you're using Gradle then including this in your project's build.gradle should exclude the support library from being exported into your main project.

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

/** Must exclude exported support jars from dependencies, or get dex duplicate class error. **/
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```

If you're using the android studio build system. Then you should go to **File** -> **project structure** and disable -> **modules**.
Go through each module the and click on the dependency tab, unchecked the export column for for the support library and google play services library.

- **Step 2**

Make sure you have downloaded Support Repository to use support library dependency in **build.gradle**.

- **Step 3**

Because you may include two same libs in your project. check your **build.gradle** file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
}
```

if your file includes compile *'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'* and compile files*('libs/android-support-v4.jar')*, it will have this problems. delete this sentence: *compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')*
To Change Make it

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' 
}
```

- **Steep 4**

If you are try the way but not solve the problem than this this another way . hope you will solve the problem. Simple go to  Project Folder Remove  .gradle  .idea  folder And Go to **yourproject\apps\build** Remove All Directory in this Build Folder Now go to Android Studio And sync your project with gradle once using the button.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582318/cant-add-junit-to-test-and-androidtest/ I tried the exclude option, but then nothing of my support lib is found anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable instant run option, it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs when you create a new project based on an existing one.

Bellow was how i fixed it:

- First make sure you've set **multiDexEnabled true**
- Delete all generated folders like **.gradle**, **.idea** and **build** when your project is still opened in android studio.
- And then **invalidate cache** and **restart the project**.

I think it should work after that.