# Can't add JUnit to test and androidTest

Tags: android, junit, android-testing

I need JUnit in both test folders. So I added

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

But as soon as I add JUnit to the androidTest I cannot run the tests, because of the error thrown[in this log.](https://pastebin.com/avrbjdgb)

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

EDIT: I removed the gradle-aware build from the run configuration. Now it says that my `TestSuite` is empty, but there are tests annotated with `@Test`

Answer (score 1):

Hava a try with this in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {   

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: So espresso includes JUnit?

Comment: Pretty much the same stack trace

Comment: i don't know . it automatic created by android studio. and solve my Junit test problem.