# Android Studio buildbox error java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, android-support-library, android-multidex

hey when i try to build my apk on android i got this error i don't what it means can you help me ? :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class
```

here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.frgg.apps.thetri"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')

}
```

Error does not show up during gradle sync. But show up when i try to build the apk

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\hotrod\Desktop\APPS\android5\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\Users\hotrod\Desktop\APPS\android5\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Users\hotrod\Desktop\APPS\android5\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

Answer (score 1):

**Remove**

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar') //Remove from Local Drive
```

**Use**

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

**FYI**

> Remove above library from local libs folder also

Finally, **Clean-Rebuild and Run** .

Comment: @jnijna remove from local `libs` folder also

Comment: i got another error now i'll put it in next comment

Comment: @jnijna read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665599/error-com-android-dx-command-main-in-android-studio-2-3